# How to create custom header and footer with minutes and fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, footer

I'm using the minutes package from https://ctan.org/pkg/minutes and changed the header and footer with fancyhdr:

```
% Minutes
\usepackage{minutes}

% Header & Footer
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyfoot[L]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{Seite {\thepage} von \pageref{LastPage}}
```

Is there a way to set the header `\fancyhead[C]{}` to the topic of the current page and the footer `\fancyfoot[L]{}` to the name set in `\begin{Protokoll}{Protokoll Jugendausschuss}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A topic is a section, and `\section` puts information in `\leftmark` or `\rightmark` depending on the documentclass.

If your document is `article` based (including `scrart`), it would be:

```
\fancyhead[C]{\leftmark}
```

If it is report based, or anything that has chapters, it would be:

```
\fancyhead[C]{\rightmark}
```

You could also redefine `\sectionmark` to use the mark of your choice.
For mor information, read the `fancyhdr` documentation.

Comment: Used this snippet to display the first topic on the page in the header: [https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/554269/242011](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/554269/242011)